# Running Git commands in powershell

Tags: git, powershell, command, prompt

I am trying to create a batch file (.bat) that will run a Powershell script to execute GIT commands so that I can run the batch file without needing to manually write the commands each time in GIT BASH. Is there a way to use GIT commands in Powershell or to invoke the GitHub.exe with commands to run?

Comment: Why would you write a script in one language (batch) to call a script in another language (PowerShell)? Also, do you need any GitHub-specific functionality, or would regular Git commands be sufficient?

Comment: I mainly need github specific functionality

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but on windows Git Shell is Powershell. Any commands you want to enter can be stored in a ps script file (script.ps1) and called from the shell (.\script.ps1).

Answer (score 0):

Please try Posh git. It is the default git shell of the Github windows GUI client.